# Changing existing record when saving new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

Problem: I have records that act like information snapshots, and I need to be able to change a yes/no field from False to True on the current existing record when I save a new record.

For arguments sake, records X and Y are the same subject, just at different point in time (same document, different revisions). I need to save a new record, record Z, which is the same subject with today's updates. When I save record Z, I want record Y to have a checkbox modified from False to True to show it is obsolete.

When saving a new record, I do have an unbound text box that displays the existing record number (named txtID). Is there a way I can piggyback a reference to that box in order to change a check box control (named chkObs) on that record?

My current coding to save a record is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenTable "tblTasks", acViewNormal
  DoCmd.Requery
  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tasks")

  rs.AddNew
  rs("Namefield").Value = Me.NameD.Value
  rs("Reqt").Value = Me.ReqT.Value
  rs("Plant").Value = Me.Plant.Value
  rs("Requestor").Value = Me.Requestor2.Value + " " + Me.Requestor.Value
  rs("TaskDue").Value = Me.TDD.Value
  rs("AssignedERDM").Value = Me.AE.Value
  rs("Package").Value = Me.SUBN.Value
  rs("Comments").Value = Me.COM.Value
  rs("RequestRec").Value = Me.DRR.Value
  rs("Hold").Value = Me.H.Value
  rs("QuantityT").Value = Me.QT.Value
  rs("QuantityC").Value = Me.QC.Value
  rs("QuantityO").Value = Me.QR.Value
  rs("ERDMLogged").Value = Me.ELT.Value
  rs("Closed").Value = Me.Cl.Value
  rs("Hyperlink").Value = Me.hy.Value
  rs("DateMod").Value = Me.lm.Value
  rs("StatusAW").Value = Me.SSO.Value
  rs("CompleteDate").Value = Me.CD.Value

  rs.Update
  DoCmd.Close acTable, "tblTasks", acSaveYes
  DoCmd.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: You can save the record ID to a global variable or to an unbound textbox or to a TempVar. Then reference that variable when needed. Run an UPDATE action SQL. Or you can just Date/Time stamp each entry and only the latest record is 'current', all others would be 'obsolete'. Why do you need code to add records? Why not a bound form for data entry?

Comment: Is this a multi-user split database? I expect if multiple users are entering records the yes/no field edit by code will get 'out of sync'.